# Determinant of ModK Reduction of Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modular-arithmetic, sudoku

Let $M:=(m_{ij})$ be a square ($ n \times n $) matrix with entries in $\{ 1,2,3,.., n\}$  ,and non-zero determinant $D$ . Let $M_k$ be its reduction Mod($k$) ; $k=2,3,.., n-1$ , i.e., $M_k:=(m_{ij} mod(k)) $. Is the determinant of $M_k$ also non-zero? Is there a formula relating $Det M$ with $Det M_k $? I can see that in the Mod2 reduction, $M_2$ is a permutation matrix, so that it's invertible.
As motivation, *not* needed to solve the problem, though,  I'm thinking of viewing Sudoku puzzles, as in https://www.websudoku.com/ as matrices. There is a result that the determinant of a $\ 9 \times 9$ Sudoku is divisible by $405$. I'm curious about what to happen to the determinant when reducing the matrix $mod (k); k=2,3,..,8$ ( and mod each of $2,3,.., n-1$  for general $n$.
Thank You.

Comment: Note that since det is a *polynomial* in the entries $\,a_{ij}\,$ we have $\bmod k\!:\ \det(a_{ij})\equiv \det(a_{ij}\bmod k),\,$ by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).